# VirtualBox bridged adapter works for everything EXCEPT guest to host

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I have two PCs on a wired LAN: `ENTROPER-PC` and `KINICKIE-PC`.  `ENTROPER-PC` is running VirtualBox with an Ubuntu Server instance called db1, using a bridged network adapter.

All three computers are identified by the router and issued `192.168.1.x` IP addresses.

I can `ping ENTROPER-PC` from `KINICKIE-PC` and vice-versa.

I can `ping db1` from `KINICKIE-PC` and vice-versa.

I **cannot** `ping db1` from `ENTROPER-PC`, nor can I `ping ENTROPER-PC` from `db1`.  They are able to resolve the IPs, but ping times out.

I can even run MySQL Workbench on `KINICKIE-PC`, and connect to `mysql` running on `db1`.  But I **can't** do that from `ENTROPER-PC`.

What could the issue be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently ran into the same problem and resolved it by downgrading.

If you are on 5.0.4 on Windows - try to uninstall and reinstall with 5.0.2.  I donwloaded it [here](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.0.2/).  If you were using the extension pack in your VM, make sure to download an install that anew as well.